# How to use onDismiss method on the declaration context?

Tags: java, android

I have a `dialogFragment` and I need to do some code when is dismissed on the same context where it is called, this call is made from a class which is not an activity or fragment.

What I want to know is how to use this onDismiss method here:

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = ImageDialog.newInstance(opti);
dialogFragment.onDismiss(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
});
dialogFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

It gives me an error on `super.onDismiss(dialog);`

> Cannot resolve method 'onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)'

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnDismissListener should be like this

```
      dialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                           //your code

                }
            });
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you! and it seems like `super.onDismiss(dialog);` is not needed.